# simple bpel workflow : select query return multiple rows

Tags: wsdl, wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

I have to implement a simple bpel workflow, which only executes a select query on database. I have been able to create a Data Service wsdl file. Its flow is attached along with this question as an image file. Please have a look at that first. If you see the image, I some how ended up making a complex structure for parameter "Name" (auto-magically generated wsdl code by wso2 Data Service Server). It has a complex element called "Customer" which has 2 string values "Name" and "nid". I have also copied the wsdl file in case you need to see it. Here: http://pastebin.com/QTKZbdzn

I believe I am not sending any input parameters, while when I try to directly invoke the Data Service without Receive module, it gives an error, saying "No Start activity has been defined for the process".
[image: DataService WSDL]

Anyone who has implemented a similar BPEL workflow for the Data Service, please let me know. The data service works fine! I have tested it separately. thanks!

UPDATE

---

I ended up making a BPM like this:
I have to change the DSS also, so that I provide some input to the BPM. Like rather than "select * from customer" I am now implementing "select * from customer where nid = ?". It proved to be pretty succesfull. Thanks for helping me out joergl & vimesh. But if you still figure out how query with no where clause would work, update it here.[image: bpm]

Comment: I haven't implemented a WSO2 data service, but I can give a few hints on BPEL. In a BPEL process, you have to have a start activity which can be a `receive` or a `pick`. That's what t[he specification says](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/wsbpel-v2.0-OS.html#_Toc164738484). Your solution could be to start your process once with such an activity, keep it alive somehow, and then you can execute your repetivite logic in an `onAlarm` `eventHandler` with `repeatEvery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a bpel flow with data service.
The very first thing we need to do is adding a receive element in the bpel flow. Actually it let us to send a request to the bps and at the same time bps makes a new instance with the request. 
  So then you can do whatever you wish, like invoking ESB proxies, DSS services, etc. while invoking the external service you can parameters to that request. Even though you are not sending any input parameters to the DSS service you should make a request to the DSS inside BPS in the correct format.(I mean the body part)
  You can simply go ahead with the bpel samples available in [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/BPEL+Samples) and then better start with DSS integrations.

Comment: hello vimesh, do you mind sharing similar bpel workflow with me the samples doesnt give me a clear insight of the following. I am not sure about these points: 1. Do I have to use a loop to handle a DS that returns multiple rows (like select * from table)? 2. As you mentioned that I have to make a request to DSS even though I a not using any parameters. Is it the name of the DS? 3. Lastly do you think the complex datastructure like "customer" for instance can create a problem here? thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ok I'll make and share a sample with you.